# Measuring transport time between two nodes

Tags: linux, networking, udp

my goal is to measure the transport time between two network nodes, using different routers (and set ups), different network adapters (and set up) and different data-volumes.

My hardware set-up are single-board-computers with Debian CLI installed and are reachable over ssh.

**The Question**: If there any Linux CLI tool to measure the transport time?

I heard from `tcpdump`, which visualises the TCP-header. But I use UDP and I can't find any good tool for UDP (maybe because UDP don't have this information in it's header).

My first approach was to write two own small programs: a sender-receiver, which measure the time, and a repeater. But I think, that measuring in the application layer leads to unpredictable errors. So I'm looking for a tool, which uses lower layer.

Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: https://iperf.fr/

Comment: What do you mean by transportation time? Is it a longer running process? Maybe just use `time` to see how long it takes? As for the delay a simple ping would get you the round trip time.

Comment: @Seth The data which has to send on the network are sensor data and commands. To have a better understanding of our control loop we examine the latency between all nodes. The sensor packages are some hundred bytes but the come with a frequency up to 500 Hz. And we have 20 active connections parallel.

Comment: Besides tcpdump you could use WireShark. Understanding that kind of information and especially if you reach such a high speed might be a problem though. It does sound like you're more interested in the timing of the packages than the actual network latency?

Comment: At the end we want to set-up a real-time able network. So predictability of latency is important to achieve stability. I will try `wireshark`!